# How to make REST API call to Apache Nifi

Tags: rest, apache-nifi

In My data flow, I am writing the data to a csv and naming the file along with timestamp. After that PUTFILE processor is placing this file in a folder location. I want to make resp api call to this and get the name of files from Apache Nifi and show the file details in application UI. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Check handlehttprequest and handlehttpresponse processors

Answer (score 2):

You can use [HandleHttpRequest](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.7.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.HandleHttpRequest/) to actively listen to incoming requests. Here's what your processor configuration should look like:

[image]

For simplicity, I've allowed all paths while listening to any requests.

Once you receive a request, the next step is to  proceed with your operation (Getting the name of files in your case). Finally attach a [HandleHttpResponse](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.7.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.HandleHttpResponse/index.html) processor in the end to send the response to the client.

[image]

Using HTTP response code **200** here as it means the status is **OK**. [HandleHttpResponse](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.7.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.HandleHttpResponse/index.html) responds to the client with any incoming flowfile content. So, if you route the list of your filenames in a single flowfile to this processor, it will share the content to the one who requested it.

Here's a sample end to end flow:

[image]

Comment: If this answer helped you, don't forget to mark this answer as accepted :)